# Setting values using a GUI

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I've been looking at the documentation, but am confused as to how to set a variable using Tkinter.

I set the variables usually just through the script such as:

```
nb=5
path='/Users/ashleighclayton/Files
navg=24
sdthresh=25
absstepthresh=100
```

However, I would like to be able to set these values using a GUI. 
At the moment I have this GUI built, but I'm struggling to impletmemnt this , even though it seems simple. (Also note they are integers and not strings in most cases)

```
class Application(Frame):
    def exc(self):
            execfile('currentmethod merlin.py',{'nb':nb,'path':path, 'navg':navg, 'sdthresh':sdthresh, 'absstepthresh':absstepthresh})

    def exe(self):
        execfile('new method merlin.py',{'nb':nb,'path':path, 'navg':navg, 'sdthresh':sdthresh, 'absstepthresh':absstepthresh} )    

    numblades=IntVar()


    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.CRTM = Button(self)
        self.CRTM["text"] = "CRTM",
        self.CRTM["command"] = self.exc
        self.CRTM.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.ERTM = Button(self)
        self.ERTM["text"] = "ERTM",
        self.ERTM["command"] = self.exe
        self.ERTM.pack({"side": "left"})

        # this is what I attempted, but I'm unsue how to set the input as the variable. 
        self.nb = Entry(self)
        self.nb.pack(side = RIGHT)


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Sorry, I'm new to Tkinter, so any help will be really appreciated, or even just pointing me to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the textvariable config option and a Tkinter variable,  but you can also use insert. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable for Entry

```
self.entryVar=Tkinter.Stringvar()
```

Then link it with your Entry widget

```
self.nb = Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVar)
```

Then to get the value of Entry widget,use

```
self.entryVar.get()
```

Comment: when I want to use nb, how do I actually access it? So nb is specified in the method `exe`, but how do retrieve it out of the GUI? Sorry! .p.. thanks for the help :)

Comment: if you want to set the values from the GUI to the script,you can always use a Dictionary for getting & setting these values